# Podman container aliases give "bad address" when pinged

Tags: docker-compose, docker-network, podman

I have a podman network. Containers can communicate by IPs, but not by the alias/container names.
Here is my network settings when inspected:

```
[
    {
        "args": {
            "podman_labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.network": "prom-net",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "printer-prometheus",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.23.2"
            }
        },
        "cniVersion": "0.4.0",
        "name": "printer-prometheus_prom-net",
        "plugins": [
            {
                "bridge": "cni-podman3",
                "hairpinMode": true,
                "ipMasq": true,
                "ipam": {
                    "ranges": [
                        [
                            {
                                "gateway": "10.101.192.129",
                                "subnet": "10.101.192.128/26"
                            }
                        ]
                    ],
                    "routes": [
                        {
                            "dst": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "host-local"
                },
                "isGateway": true,
                "type": "bridge"
            },
            {
                "capabilities": {
                    "portMappings": true
                },
                "type": "portmap"
            },
            {
                "backend": "",
                "type": "firewall"
            },
            {
                "type": "tuning"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am using docker-compose to start the pods.

```
            "Networks": {
                "printer-prometheus_prom-net": {
                    "EndpointID": "",
                    "Gateway": "10.101.192.129",
                    "IPAddress": "10.101.192.131",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 26,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "96:2e:67:d1:45:ec",
                    "NetworkID": "printer-prometheus_prom-net",
                    "DriverOpts": null,
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "5712fb063d92",
                        "blackbox_exporter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
```

If I ping either alias or the container name I get `ping: bad address '5712fb063d92'`.

I can ping the IP without an issue. Using the same compose file and docker, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing [dnsname](https://github.com/containers/dnsname) and adding the following to my plugins list in /etc/cni/net.d/network_name solved the issue

```
     {
        "type": "dnsname",
        "domainName": "dns.podman",
        "capabilities": {
           "aliases": true
        }
```